# Change text on page to title Wordpress with functions

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I know how to write a function that will change a specific text to another in the pages of the site.

For example:

```
function replace_text($text) 
{
    $text = str_replace('WP', '<strong>WP</strong>', $text);
    $text = str_replace('WordPress', 'WordPress', $text);
    return $text;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

Please tell me how can I make it so that a specific word always changes to the page title? I do not understand how should I use the get_the_title () function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_the_title()` requires a postID - which can be taken from `get_the_ID()`:

```
function replace_text($text) 
{
    $post_title = get_the_title(get_the_ID());
    return str_replace('SOME_WORD', $post_title, $text);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```